# Matplotlib: Creating a colorbar based on datetime module for a series of lines in a plot

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, plot, colorbar

I'm trying to color code a series of lines in a plot based on the python module datetime. I've tried mapping the the datetime data (as a numpy array) to RGBA using ScalarMappable; however, I'm running into difficulties. Please find a segment of the code below:

```
import datetime as dt    
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as mplcm
import matplotlib.colors as colors

clmap     = 'jet'
cm        = plt.get_cmap(clmap)
iDT       = dt.datetime(2012,1,1,0,0,0)
fDT       = dt.datetime(2012,1,2,0,0,0)
cNorm     = colors.Normalize( vmin=iDT, vmax=fDT )
scalarMap = mplcm.ScalarMappable( norm=cNorm, cmap=cm )
scalarMap.set_array(retDays)        

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_color_cycle( [scalarMap.to_rgba(x) for x in retDays] )
```

Where retDays is a numpy array of datetime values.

I get the following error when using set_color_cycle:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you write out the list `[scalarMap.to_rgba(x) for x in retDays]`?

Comment: @ysakamoto. Unfortunately, I can't write out the list. I think the error is occurring in scalarMap.to_rgba(x). I don't think to_rgba accepts the datetime object. Thanks!!